# is inaccessible within this context

Tags: c++

Пишу текстовую игру. Перенес общие функции в другой класс и возникла ошибка. Как исправить? Вот какая ошибка.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:13:47: error: ‘void Living::set_pos(Map*)’ is inaccessible within this context
  player.set_pos ( map->find_map_coord ( 'D' ) );
                                               ^
In file included from Player.h:3,
                 from main.cpp:4:
Living.h:11:8: note: declared here
   void set_pos ( Map *pos );
        ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:47: error: ‘Living’ is not an accessible base of ‘Player’
  player.set_pos ( map->find_map_coord ( 'D' ) );
                                               ^
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Вот main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Loader.h"
#include "Player.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Loader loader;
    loader.load ( "map" );
    Map *map = loader.get_map ( );
    map->set_sizes ( loader.width, loader.height );
    Player player;
    player.set_pos ( map->find_map_coord ( 'D' ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Вот living.h

```
#ifndef __living__
#define __living__
#include "Map.h"
#include <cstring>

class Living {
    protected:
        Map *pos;
        char *name;
    public:
        void set_pos ( Map *pos );
        void set_name ( const char *name );
        void walk_north ( );
        void walk_west ( );
        void walk_south ( );
        void walk_east ( );
};
#endif
```

Вот living.cpp

```
#include "Living.h"

void Living::set_name ( const char *name )
{
    int length = strlen ( name );
    this->name = new char [ length + 1 ];
    strncpy ( this->name, name, length );
    this->name [ length ] = 0;
}

void Living::walk_north ( )
{
    if ( pos->north->get_place ( ) == '*' ) {
    }
    pos = pos->north;
}

void Living::walk_west ( )
{
}

void Living::walk_south ( )
{
}

void Living::walk_east ( )
{
}

void Living::set_pos ( Map *pos )
{
    this->pos = pos;
}
```

Вот player.h

```
#include <string.h>
#include "Map.h"
#include "Living.h"

class Player : Living {
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У `class`-ов родители по умолчанию приватные. Естественно, что вы не можете получить доступ к методам `private` родителя.

Нужно вот так:

```
class Player : public Living {};
```

Comment: Спасибо, а я сначала делал так, но были и другие ошибки, и я точно не знал зачем делать public class, но теперь понел.