# Ошибка при попытке включить содержимое одного класса в другой

Tags: c++, классы, вложенные-классы

Я еще зеленый новичок, поэтому за ошибки прошу ногами не бить)
Имеется следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;    

class State
{
public:
    //...          
    void GetInfoAboutState(){//...}    
};   

class Society  //  общество
{
//...
public:
    void GetInfoAboutSociety()
    { //...   }        
};

class Primitive_Society : Society // Так выглядит наследование
{
//...

public:
   //...        
    void GetInfoAboutPrimitiveSociety()
    {
        GetInfoAboutSociety();
        //...
    }
    //...
};


class Slave_Owning_Society : Primitive_Society
{
protected:
    //...    
public:
//...     
    void GetInfoAbouSlaveOwningSociety()
    {
        GetInfoAboutPrimitiveSociety();
        //...  
    }       
};    

class Feudal_Society : Slave_Owning_Society
{
protected:
   //...    
public:     
    //...
    void GetInfoAboutFeudalSociety()
    {
        GetInfoAbouSlaveOwningSociety();
        GetInfoaboutState();
    }
};
```

Задачка такая: нужно в классе Feudal_Society сделать вывод государств (класс State)/
Сделал класс `State`, не могу через функцию `GetInfoaboutState` получить нужную информацию.

Компилятор выдает ошибки:

> C3861 GetInfoaboutState: идентификатор не найден E0020    идентификатор
> "GetInfoaboutState" не определен

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1) Ошибка с регистром символов. Вызывается функция `GetInfoaboutState`, но объявлена функция `GetInfoAboutState`. 2) Функция `GetInfoAboutState` есть только внутри класса `State`. Внутри класса `Feudal_Society` и _его предков_ такой функции нет. 3) Если решите унаследоваться от `State`, то имейте ввиду, что [родители по умолчанию приватные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/920040).

Comment: Реализации к вопросу не относятся, поэтому я убрал больше половины кода

Answer (score 0):

Закрытое наследование подразумевает, что наследник может использовать все открытые и защищенные члены базового класса, но он не имеет этих членов.

только `class Primitive_Society` и его друзья могут   использовать  функции члены закрытого базового класса. В данном случаи `Society::GetInfoAboutSociety`, поэтому:

```
void GetInfoAboutPrimitiveSociety()
{
    GetInfoAboutSociety();
    //...
}
```

правильная реализация. Но `class Slave_Owning_Society : Primitive_Society`, и `class Feudal_Society : Slave_Owning_Society` никак не могут использовать функции_члены  закрытого базового класса своих закрытых базовых классов. В частности,  `Society::GetInfoAboutSociety` для них не доступна(закрытый интерфейс).

Обратите внимание на:

- нужно классу просто иметь базу для использования или он должен быть  разновидностью базового класса
- качество кода и количество кода для оформления вопроса

**Обновление:**

Так как `Primitive_Society` по идее является разновидностью `Society`, то нужно это выразить кодом именно так, то есть наследование делать открытым:

```
class Primitive_Society : public Society
```

тогда класс будет иметь свою собственную `GetInfoAboutState` и другие члены, унаследованные от базового класса, и проблема отпадет.

Comment: То есть, чтобы использовать метод GetInfoAboutState, мне нужно класс State включить в класс Feudal_Society или Slave_Owning_Society, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Billy Bones@ читайте обновление и хорошо изучайте тему. Одними вопросами тему не изучить...